# How to fill up 2 views in a FrameLayout with available space

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 2 views. I want the 2 views to fill up the screen, just like with a LinearLayout. View 1 should go in the top right corner and should be smaller. I need FrameLayout because I have more views on top of this, so this question is about how to get this working with FrameLayout.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/videoScreen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />

</FrameLayout>
```

For Nexus 4 it works, but for other resolutions ofcourse it doesn't:
[image]

Comment: Could you nest a LinearLayout inside your FrameLayout?  That way you are still using a FrameLayout at the top level, but you get the benefit of LinearLayout too.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/videoScreen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```